# Cannot convert jsonArray element to integer

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

```
do{
    let resultJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions())
    let arrayJSON = resultJSON as! NSArray

    let success:NSInteger = arrayJSON["success"] as! NSInteger

    if (success == 1 ) ....
```

json data is the response from the server, i am trying to convert it to integer  but i get the conversation error.

Comment: before doing anything, could you please print the data? the example i showed to you expected that the response is json array. let's see your response in order to parse it correctly

Comment: data =<7b227375 63636573 73223a30 2c226572 726f725f 6d657373 61676522 3a224e6f 20557365 72227d>

Comment: what does `print(response)` generate ?

Comment: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f8ea40507d0> { URL: myurl } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Mon, 05 Oct 2015 16:46:50 GMT";
    Expires = "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=10, max=150";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = Apache;
    "Set-Cookie" = "PHPSESSID=bd51710ab7f881ff59927393f0d6f050; path=/";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.3.29";
} }

Comment: also please do `print(data!)` and show me the result

Comment: <7b227375 63636573 73223a30 2c226572 726f725f 6d657373 61676522 3a224e6f 20557365 72227d>

Comment: do `let resultJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions())` and `print("\(resultJSON)")` and update me pleaes

Comment: {
    "error_message" = "No User";
    success = 0;
}

Comment: wait i will give you an answer

Comment: check my answer please

Comment: please check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working exmaple (tested on my machine)

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            if let data = data{
                print("data =\(data)")
                do{
                let resultJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions())
                let resultDictionary = resultJSON as? NSDictionary

                    let success = resultDictionary!["success"]!
                    let successInteger = success as! Int
                    print("success = \(success)")
                    if successInteger == 1 {
                        print("yes")
                    }else{
                        print("no")
                    }
                }catch _{
                    print("Received not-well-formatted JSON")
            }

            }
            if let response = response {
                print("url = \(response.URL!)")
                print("response = \(response)")
                let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
                print("response code = \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
            }



        })
        task.resume()
```

where the response is:

```
{ "error_message" : "No User", "success" : 0}
```

#### Note

you said that your server responnes as:

```
{ "error_message" = "No User"; success = 0; }
```

and this is **not** a valid json, you should correct it to match the json that i gave to you

Comment: When i do this ->  if(success == 1) {} i get this error This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.

Comment: @RULE101 okay I am creating a real REST web service to test your situation, just 5 minutes and I finish testing

Comment: @RULE101 check my answer now please

Comment: Server responses valid JSON but xcode debugger shows it wrong with ; which is very strange

Answer (score 1):

You're casting `resultJSON` as an `NSArray` but then you try to use it as a dictionary by subscripting "success".

If the response is a dictionary, then cast the result as a dictionary:

```
let result = resultJSON as! NSDictionary
let success = result["success"] as! NSInteger
```

If the response is an array of dictionaries, then first select one of the items before subscripting.

```
let arrayJSON = resultJSON as! NSArray
let success = arrayJSON[0]["success"] as! NSInteger
```

*Note: when possible, prefer using Swift's typed arrays an dictionaries rather than Foundation's NSArray and NSDictionary. Also you should avoid force casting with `!`, it's better to unwrap optionals safely with `if let ... = ... as? ...` or any other mechanism.*

**Update**

Here's an example:

```
do {
    let resultJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions())

    var success = 0

    if let dictJSON = resultJSON as? [String:AnyObject] {
        if let successInteger = dictJSON["success"] as? Int {
            success = successInteger
        } else {
            print("no 'success' key in the dictionary, or 'success' was not compatible with Int")
        }
    } else {
        print("unknown JSON problem")
    }

    if success == 1 {
        // yay!
    } else {
        // nope
    }
```

In this example I'm using a Swift dictionary `[String:AnyObject]` instead of an NSDictionary, and I'm using a Swift integer `Int` instead of Foundation's `NSInteger`. I'm also typecasting with `if let` instead of forcing.

Comment: I am new in swift. Thank you. Can you please give some examples explaining your note.

Comment: Cannot use dictJSON["userID"] after if success == 1 i get use of unresolved identifier

Comment: Well this is a new different error, if you get there, it means I've resolved your original question. :) Of course `dictJSON` is unresolved later because it is local to `if let dictJSON ...`, it exists only inside this branch. Either use it inside this branch or assign the result to another variable to use later.